# Advaita Vedanta Gitas

Tags: advaita, reference-request, gita

Sorry to open this question up since I didn't find any related question anywhere.

There are 64 known Gitas in Hinduism which are classic texts that summarize various pillars of Hinduism. I wish to get a list of all the important Gitas that are directly associated with Advaita Vedanta.

A few of them are:

- [Ashtavakra Gita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtavakra_Gita) (by Sage Ashtavakra)
- [Avadhuta Gita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avadhuta_Gita) (by Sage Dattatreya)
- [Uttara Gita](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/uttara-gita-idk878/) (by Sri Krishna)

Are there any more such associated Gitas? (or Upanishads that are also regarded as a Gita?)
Please help me get a complete list of references. Thank you everyone for your cooperation in advance.

Comment: Yog Vashistha is also like a Gita.

Comment: @YuvrajRathore I guess it is like a long epic like text (smruti) than Upanishad (shruti).

Comment: Well Gitas are not shruti they are smriti. They are the philosophical text. Yog Vashistha too is a philosophical text it starts like the Bhagavad Gita. The 1st Ch of the Bhagavad Gita is Melancholy of Arjun, and the 1st Ch of Yog Vashistha is Melancholy of Rama. Indeed, Yoga Vashistha is not a typical Gita (it covers a lots of Ground) but it is like a Gita.        Siddha Gita, Vashistha Gita, Brahma Gita-These 3 are the extraction from Yog Vashistha which are taken as Advait GIta.

Comment: @YuvrajRathore They are *smrutis* but accepted as Upanishads, that's why they can be thought of as *shrutis* too. Yoga Vashistha is not well known as a Gita, but as a historical text such as Ramayana

Comment: 'Gita' just means 'song'. There are many shastras that are called Gita. There is no perscribed or complete list

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Tho, I'm not sure here, but I remember reading somewhere that there are *64* such songs and those *gitas* are accepted as Upanishads. But yeah, any knowledge of such Gita would be very helpful in compiling the list of Advaita Gitas.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Yeah the gitas are like shruti. They deal with the topic of Upanishads. Bhagvad gita is like an essence of Upanishad.                                 
Siddha Gita, Vashistha Gita, Brahma Gita-These 3 are the Advait Gita-They are in Yoga Vashistha.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha you will find same things more or less in Gitas.i think better to study saint like raman maharishi who expounds truth in simple manner